# Any recommended Rails Deployment tutorial book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused by Rails Deployment.

I followed this guide(https://github.com/rocodev/guides/wiki/setup-production-development) to setup environment on my server.

I have done all the installation proccess, but it doesn't work!!

When I run 'cap deploy:setup', it asked me to type password, and I typed, but it said permission denied.

I couldn't find out what the problem is, and I can't clearly know some parts of this guide.

Are there any resources(maybe a book) can give me a robust understanding about Rails Deployment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of books on Rails deployment practices:

- [Deploying Rails: Automate, Deploy, Scale, Maintain, and Sleep at Night](http://pragprog.com/book/cbdepra/deploying-rails) published by the PragProgs. Written in 2012, and focusing on Rails 3.x, but should still be mostly up to date (really nothing much has changed in the space in the last 2 years). (Or, the old versions of the tools aren't super broken and still widely used).
- [Reliably Deploying Rails Applications](https://leanpub.com/deploying_rails_applications), published via LeanPub. 80% done as of this writing, and does incorporate the bleeding edge tools.

I haven't read the latter book, but I have read the former book and liked it reasonably well.

Comment: +1 on Deploying Rails ... solid book (I, too, have not read the second).

Comment: +1 Reliably Deploying Rails, the first book is good but quite out dated and the tools have changed a lot since it was written. For me the sample code  in the second one worked out of the box

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to read a book on rails deployment for fixing production issues. Once you complete a book, It's not mean you able to deploy your app seamless manner. Still issue will occur and you will run to Google. We always leant form our mistakes and by fixing them.

I would suggest have a look to small blogs and tutorial.

[Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)
[HOW TO DEPLOY RAILS APPLICATION TO VPS](http://blog.sudobits.com/2013/01/07/how-to-deploy-rails-application-to-vps/?goback=.gde_27822_member_222275867)

[Setup A Ubuntu VPS For Hosting Ruby On Rails Applications](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/)

[Deploying Rails to Dreamhost VPS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDMZk1ycCBY)

[Capistrano Tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks)

[Capistrano Tasks (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks-revised)

If you really want a deep understanding of rails development. Go ahead with below book.
[Deploying Rails: Automate, Deploy, Scale, Maintain, and Sleep at Night](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356956)

Answer (score 0):

I started with these two RailsCasts:

1. Manual setup of a rails environment on a VPS: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps
2. Automating the above with capistrano: http://railscasts.com/episodes/337-capistrano-recipes

There's a lot of other tools / options, but this is a pretty common (simple) way of managing and deploying servers.  I use this basic setup for managing 2 different clustered environments, with 3 servers each (one of them is not rails) + an NFS between them - works well.

BUT, if you can, I'd really look at PaaS (like Heroku) options.  I also run a more vanilla rails web app on this platform and it saves me a lot of time in server maintenance, management, and scripting.